# embed python intepreter in c application

Tags: python, linux

I have a big C application that runs on linux. I want to embed a python-3.6 interpreter inside my application. From what I understand it is just a matter of including python source in my compilation and executing:

```
#include <Python.h>
void exec_interactive_interpreter(int arg, char** argv)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  Py_Main(argc, argv);
  Py_Finalize();
}
```

from my code. However I'm not sure how the compilation process works. Looking in the [python source](https://github.com/python/cpython) I don't see any master makefile. How should my application makefile compile the python source?